# How to play HTML5 video using Qt WebKit

Tags: qt5, qtwebkit, qwebview

I have created one QtWebkit based app , and trying to load below mention URL, which if we open in Firefox , it will show as a HTML5 video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYc2jP4LLGo&html5=True

In my application I am getting youtube html5 player getting loaded, but it is not displaying any video content.

I tried even in the browser sample application which comes along with the Qt SDK installtion.
I am getting the same result as my app is.

below mention is the code which I wrote

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView();
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
view->load(QUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTl3U6aSd2w&html5=True"));
view->setGeometry(50,50, 800, 600);
view->show();
```

Machine :- both Windows 7 X64, Windows7 ultimate X86
Qt5.1 SDK

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

*QT5.2* ( http://qt-project.org/downloads ) now supports `<video>` tag (html5).

if using *QT-32bit*, the system must have installed video codecs for *32bit*.

*K-lite codec* download:
http://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_full.htm

Comment: I know this is old, but, do you know if qtwebkit 2.1 supports video in ts format?

Comment: @PauloGustavo I believe that it does not support this format. Note: but the qtwebkit been discontinued and removed in new versions (unfortunately).

Comment: Thanks for you answer!!